# A possibility of a bridge network in sending ip4 pings by adding wlan0 to br0

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6

So I have a wifi chip connected to an application processor running linux, that's currently configured to be running wpa supplicant, and I see `wlan0` interface has an ipv6.

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:7f:61:a0:41  
          inet6 addr: fe80::203:7fff:fe61:a041/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3000 
          RX bytes:159930 (156.1 KiB)  TX bytes:5534 (5.4 KiB)
```

I was able to send pings between IPv6-based addresses, but now I need to establish the same with IPv4-based addresses, but as you can see, the `wlan0` as shown above doesn't have any IPv4 address assigned.

I tried setting a static IP via `ifconfig wlan0 <ip>` and now I see `inet addr` associated with the `wlan0` when I do ifconfig, as shown below:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:7f:61:a0:41  
          inet addr:172.30.100.14  Bcast:172.30.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::203:7fff:fe61:a041/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:606 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3000 
          RX bytes:179540 (175.3 KiB)  TX bytes:11727 (11.4 KiB)
```

which is IPv4 address but sending pings between the two machines via IPv4-based addresses didn't work, despite ensuring the subnet mask on both machines are the same. The error is `Destination host unreachable`.
Later realized I couldn't even browse after changing the subnet mask so it set back to `255.255.255.0` via DHCP.

What am I doing wrong?

An additional thought:

Would adding an interface to bridge work in any way?

- Setting a bridge network `br0`
- assigning an ipv4 IP to `br0`
- adding `wlan0` to `br0`
- send pings from a machine configured on ipv4 on LAN to IP associated with `wlan0`

Would the above steps work? (Edit: tried it but doesn't quite seem to. Realized the subnet mask of other machine (sender) wasn't the same as the destination machine but even changing that didn't work)

Lastly, when I try to add `wlan0` to `br0`, I get `can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported`. I looked up online, and I see people suggesting to enable `4add` first but upon doing

```
# iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on
```

I get

```
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

Comment: You didn't mention in your post: does this plan include adding _other_ interfaces to br0, or just the single wlan0 interface? And if you plan have a bridge with just one member interface, what is that supposed to change over just using the same wlan0 interface for IPv4 directly?

Comment: just the single wlan0 interface -- just the wifi interface that I have up and running.

Comment: Okay, but in that case, what would the bridge _do_? Usually the entire purpose of a bridge is to have two or more ports (and relay ethernet frames between them). A bridge with one port does basically nothing.

Comment: just to clarify something: when you add an a wlan0 interface to a bridge, the IP is assigned to both the bridge and wlan0 interface or just wlan0? if the sender needs to send a packet to wlan0 through bridge, what would the destination address be?

Comment: I cannot make any sense of "send a packet to wlan0 through bridge". But as for the first question – when interfaces get added to a bridge, they completely stop doing participating in the network at L2 or L3 (that is, they no longer look at IP addresses or even MAC addresses); they literally only act like physical ports. All addresses on wlan0 would be ignored if it was part of a bridge.

Comment: Just saw a video on YouTube to clarify further: Keeping this image (https://www.imgur.com/a/Fd7yWHL) in mind, I understand it makes sense for a bridge to handle multiple devices and it directs the packets to a destination based on the MAC address that it stores. To my question, how can I enable ipv4 on each side so both ipv6 and ipv4 work and not just ipv6?

Comment: It is possible to have IPv6 and IPv4 and even multiple IP addresses on the interface. You need to think about the goal you are trying to achieve and formulate the question so it is possible to answer. This is typical [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Read this as well: [How to ask good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Reworded the question...